# Using custom fonts in pdfLaTex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I wondering whether there is a way of importing custom fonts in ttf format into pdfLaTex without changing the compiling engine?

I found an article from Overleaf: [https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I'd_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F#If_you.27re_using_pdfLaTeX_or_LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F#If_you.27re_using_pdfLaTeX_or_LaTeX)

Which gives a solution but I am not sure how to apply the same thing in TexMaker.

As a reference, below is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=1.9cm,bottom=1.9cm]{geometry}
```

While the font I'm trying to import can be found here:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/M+PLUS+1p

Comment: well normally you can. But you will have to create quite a bunch of support files (tfm, map, enc, vf) first with autoinst and install them in the right place. That is not easy. Switching the engine is simpler.

Comment: From the Overleaf document you mention: "The easiest way to use [the custom font in a ttf file] is via XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and fontspec." I would take this observation very seriously.

Comment: @Mico Just curious, in general, which engine is usually better for compiling complex diagrams and different fonts?

Comment: the diagram support is identical (more or less) across the engines but if your "different fonts" are truetype or opentype it is far far easier to use lualatex or xelatex.